# Dataweave transformation: Modify JSON value

Tags: json, mule, dataweave

I want to do the below dataweave transformation. "SourceValue" should go as
"Source" and "SrcVal" in the output payload. Could you please suggest how to do it.

Input:

```
{       "payload":[
      {
         "key":"stage",
         "value":"Completed"
      },
      {
         "key":"url",
         "value":"abc.com"
      },
      {
         "key":"SourceValue",
         "value":"abc"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following :

```
%dw 1.0
%input payload application/json
%output application/json
%var a=2
---
{
    part1: payload.payload map ((payload01 , indexOfPayload01) -> {
        "key" : "Source" when payload01.key == "SourceValue" otherwise payload01.key,
        "value" : payload01.value

    }),
     part2: payload.payload filter ($.key == "url"  or $.key == "SourceValue") map ((payload01 , indexOfPayload01) ->  
         {
         "key" : "SrcVal" when payload01.key == "SourceValue" otherwise payload01.key,
         "value" : payload01.value  
         }
     ) 

}
```